# How to change field name in collection result on Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm working Laravel collection. I would like to change some eloquent output field name. Below is my query code.

```
$labdetails =LabDetailCustom::where('labcode',$request->labcode)->get(['id','name']);
```

And resulted as below.

```
[
{
id: 65,
name: "Color"
},
{
id: 66,
name: "Apearance"
},
{
id: 67,
name: "Urobilinogen"
}
]
```

But my need is to change '`id`' to '`codename`' instead. So result should be.

```
[
{
codename: 65,
name: "Color"
},
{
codename: 66,
name: "Apearance"
},
{
codename: 67,
name: "Urobilinogen"
}
]
```

It may need to use '`map function`' that I'm not familiar. Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work as you expect:

```
$labdetails =LabDetailCustom::where('labcode',$request->labcode)
    ->get(['id as codename','name']);
```

Comment: Dear Leonardo Rossi, Work as expected. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AS` MySQL query here.

```
$labdetails = LabDetailCustom::select('id AS codename', 'name')->where('labcode', $request->labcode)->get();

$labdetails->codename;
$labdetails->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this .

```
foreach( $labdetails as $index => $labdetail) {
        $labdetails [$index]['codename'] = $labdetail['id'];
        unset($labdetails[$index]['id']);
    }
```